# proof related to Fundamental Theorem of Calculus $f$ is not necessarily continuous on an interval

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I want to solve the problems from the book "A Course of Modern Analysis" (P 65) by E.T. Whittaker & G.N. Watson. The notation in this book is a little old-fashioned and I don't really like their notation.

> If $f(x)$ is integrable when $a_1 \le x \le b_1$, when $a_1 \le a < b < b_1,$ we write
> $$
> \int_{a}^bf(x)dx = \phi(a,b),
> $$
> and if $f(b+0)$ exists, then
> $$
> \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \frac{\phi(a, b+\delta)-\phi(a, b)}{\delta} = f(b+0).
> $$

Here is my attempt for the problem:

> \begin{align*}
> \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \frac{\phi(a, b+\delta)-\phi(a, b)}{\delta}  &= \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \frac{\int_{a}^{b+ \delta}f(x)dx -\int_{a}^bf(x)dx }{\delta} \\ 
> &=  \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \frac{\int_{b}^{b + \delta}f(x)dx}{\delta}.
> \end{align*}
> Then I got stuck here.

Comment: Almost there: use the continuity of $f$ at $b^+$ i.e. use that $f(x)=f(b)+o_{\delta\to0^+}(1)$ when $x\in(b,b+\delta)$.

Comment: @Nicolas How can we use the continuity of $f$ at $b^+$ when the problem does not assume continuity of f at any point?

Comment: It is said "if $f(b+0)$ exists" which is exactly what I have written except that I have written $f(b)$ instead of $f(b+0)$.

Comment: When they say $f(b+0)$ exists, they mean $\lim_{\delta\to 0^+} f(b+\delta)$ exists. Doesn't that sound like right continuity at $b$? But you cannot use the mean value theorem proof you have in mind, since you do not have continuity on an interval.

Comment: By the way, $f(b+0)$ also means that $\lim_{\delta\to0^-}f(b+\delta)$ exists. If they wanted the restriction on the right of $b$ then they should have said $f(b+0^+)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin That makes a lot more sense. I literally thought that the author means the value $f$ at $b$ exists.

Comment: @Nicolas That makes so much sense. I didn't know what the author means by $f(b+0)$ exists.

Comment: Yeah, this is a bit old-fashioned notation, but people still do use it.

Comment: I do not find this notation old-fashioned :p

Comment: @Nicolas What does this notation $o_{\delta \to 0^+}(1)$ mean?

Comment: @Smith $0_{\delta\to0^+}(1)$ is a function which tends to 0 as $\delta\to 0^+$. It is Landau's little o notation.

Comment: By the way Whittaker and Watson's book is great. Modern texts usually tend to go overboard with abstractions and thereby some charm is lost. Old classics like this one are a real treat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general version of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Just note that $f(x) \to f(b+0)=L(\text{say}) $ as $x\to b^+$ and thus we have corresponding to a given $\epsilon>0$ a $\delta>0$ such that $$L-\epsilon <f(x) <L+\epsilon $$ whenever $b<x<b+\delta$. If $0<h<\delta$ then integrating the above inequality over interval $[b, b+h] $ we get $$h(L-\epsilon) <\int_b^{b+h} f(x)\, dx<h(L+\epsilon) $$ ie $$L-\epsilon<\frac{1}{h}\int_b^{b+h}f(x)\,dx<L+\epsilon $$ for all $h$ with $0<h<\delta$. This means (by definition of limit) that $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{1}{h}\int_b^{b+h}f(x)\,dx=L$$ which is exactly what you wanted to prove.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
& \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \frac{\phi(a, b+\delta)-\phi(a, b)}{\delta} \\
&= \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \frac{\int_{a}^{b+ \delta}f(x)dx -\int_{a}^bf(x)dx }{\delta} \\ 
&= \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \frac{\int_{b}^{b + \delta}f(x)dx}{\delta} \\
&= \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \frac{\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f(b+i\delta/n) \, \delta/n}{\delta} \tag{$f$ is integrable on $[a,b_1]$} \\
&= \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(b+i\delta/n) \\
&= f(b+) \tag{claim to be proved}
\end{align*}

To prove the claim, let $\epsilon > 0$.  Using the existence of $f(b+)$ to establish $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)-f(b+)| < \epsilon$ whenever $x \in (b,b+\delta)$.

\begin{align}
\left(\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(b+i\delta/n)\right) - f(b+) &= \left[\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (f(b+i\delta/n)-f(b+))\right] + \frac{f(b+\delta)-f(b+)}{n} \\
\left \lvert \left(\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(b+i\delta/n)\right) - f(b+) \right \rvert &< \frac{n-1}{n} \,\epsilon + \left \lvert \frac{f(b+\delta)-f(b+)}{n} \right \rvert \\
&< \epsilon + \left \lvert \frac{f(b+\delta)-f(b+)}{n} \right \rvert
\end{align}

Take $N > \left\lceil\dfrac{f(b+\delta) - f(b+)}{\epsilon}\right\rceil$.  Whenever $n \ge N$, then
$$\left \lvert \left(\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(b+i\delta/n)\right) - f(b+) \right \rvert < 2 \epsilon.$$